# How to Find Contiguous Dates within two Sets of Dates

Tags: c#, list, linq, date

All, I have two sets of dates for which I need to find all date pairs having  contiguous dates where the hours connect. I would like the result to return the start and end date for each contiguous pair or pairs of dates to be used later as arguments to a linq query against a master list which contains all possible dates.

Below : Sample data to be evaluated.  Desired output at bottom.

Thanks

```
// The result should return all pairs of start/end times (hour) where dates are contiguous. Where a set has more than two pairs, 
// the result would return the start time of the first start record and the end time of the latest end record.


var ranges = new List<DateRange>
                             {new DateRange(DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 10:00 AM"), DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 12:00 PM")),
                              new DateRange(DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 12:00 PM"), DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 02:00 PM")),
                              new DateRange(DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 02:00 PM"), DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 04:00 PM")),
                              new DateRange(DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 07:00 PM"), DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 08:00 PM")),
                              new DateRange(DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 04:00 PM"), DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 05:00 PM")),
                              new DateRange(DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 10:00 PM"), DateTime.Parse("1/19/2018 11:00 PM"))
                             };


    // Sample Result
    // Set 1
    // "1/19/2018 10:00 AM", "1/19/2018 05:00 PM"

    // Set 2
    // "1/19/2018 07:00 PM", "1/19/2018 08:00 PM"

    // Set 3
    // "1/19/2018 10:00 PM", "1/19/2018 11:00 PM"``
```

Comment: ...I don't get it.Maybe 'cause English ain't my first language. But, would it be hard for you to explain what the real life purpose is; what are you coding? =)

Comment: Those aren't lists.

Comment: The purpose is simple. Determine the start and end date for each set of dates which are contiguous in the two lists. I will use the start time of the first and the end time of the last as a range in other code. Thanks

Comment: Contiguous what? Days, hours, minutes, etc. Define "Contiguous"

Comment: Please change the sample data to be `List`s and provide a sample answer.

Comment: Those. Aren't. Lists. You tagged Linq and List, but you haven't provided an IEnumerable. We cannot help you with the question as-is. If you don't want lists, and you will always only ever have 12 variables (6 start, 6 stop with those names), say so and we will help. But if you want Linq, give us an IEnumerable. Let us know if they are nullable (eg, no endTime - still going). Are you going to go with 2 lists where startList[x] is the start time for endList[x], if you're going with a List<List<DateTime>> where List[x][0] is start, List[x][1] is stop, or a tuple, or something else.

Comment: @MichaelO'Neill  While the OP data, code, and question are not perfect; it is irrelevant to contiguous. Contiguous in general means that items share a border; and in this case, one events end time is equal to another's start time.

Comment: You may want to organize your data a little better. Maybe a _TimeBlock_ class containing a start and an end time. Then you could compare the _TimeBlocks_ to one another. That class also could have your methods for population and detection

Comment: Thanks Mad Myche - I eventually ordered the data as Date Ranges which led me to the comparison and Kiwi package.

Answer (score 0):

The example-code will not work. Because of this i have to guess what you want to do. Your example-data look like some log-in/out data of a single user.

My guess: You got no overlapping intervalls - every start is unique and there is no other start before it ends.
Example:

```
1/18/2018 10 AM - 1/18/2018 11 AM
1/18/2018 11 AM - 1/18/2018 01 PM
```

You want to merge this to..

```
1/18/2018 10 AM - 1/18/2018 01 PM
```

And this is not allowed, because it's overlapping:

```
1/18/2018 10 AM - 1/18/2018 01 PM
1/18/2018 11 AM - 1/18/2018 02 PM
```

If this is what you want to do, you should edit your question. But this could be your solution:

```
// A class for each intervall
public class MyIntervall
{
    public MyIntervall(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(params string[] args)
{
    // Your data..
    List<MyIntervall> intervalls = new List<MyIntervall>()
    {
        new MyIntervall(new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 10, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 12, 0, 0)),
        new MyIntervall(new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 12, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 14, 0, 0)),
        new MyIntervall(new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 14, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 16, 0, 0)),
        new MyIntervall(new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 19, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 20, 0, 0)),
        new MyIntervall(new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 16, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 17, 0, 0)),
        new MyIntervall(new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 22, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 23, 0, 0))
    };

    MyIntervall lastIntervall = null;
    List<MyIntervall> mergedIntervalls = new List<MyIntervall>();
    // Loop through your list.
    foreach (MyIntervall currenIntervall in intervalls.OrderBy(o => o.Start))
    {
        if (lastIntervall == null)
        {
            // Start-condition
            lastIntervall = currenIntervall;
        }
        else if (lastIntervall.End == currenIntervall.Start)
        {
            // If the last intervall ends at the start of the next one, we merge them into one bigger intervall by moving the end.
            lastIntervall.End = currenIntervall.End;
        }
        else
        {
            // If end doesn't match the next start, we know that the intervall is closed. Wo move to the next one.
            mergedIntervalls.Add(lastIntervall);
            lastIntervall = currenIntervall;
        }
    }
    // In the end, we add the last intervall to the merge-list, because it has no following intervall.
    mergedIntervalls.Add(lastIntervall);

    // output our merge-result
    int set = 0;
    foreach (MyIntervall currenIntervall in mergedIntervalls)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("#{0}: Start {1}, End {2}", ++set, currenIntervall.Start, currenIntervall.End);
    }

    // this is the result of the merge
    List<MyIntervall> resultList = new List<MyIntervall>()
    {
        new MyIntervall(new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 10, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 17, 0, 0)),
        new MyIntervall(new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 19, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 20, 0, 0)),
        new MyIntervall(new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 22, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 1, 19, 23, 0, 0))
    };
}
```

Comment: Kara - I updated my data sample to an interval/range for clarity. Your exampled returned the correct result and I will mark as an answer. Thank You